# "I will rob you of it" vs. "I will rob it of you"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, pronouns, word-order

Which of these is grammatically correct, and why?

> - I will rob you of it
> - I will rob it of you

Comment: _Rob_ and _steal_ differ in what their prototype direct object is. One _robs_ a place or a person _of_ objects, but _steals_ objects _from_ places or people. The modern phrasal verb _rip off_ works either way -- you can _rip off the book from Bill_, or you can _rip Bill off_; generally if the victim is the DO, the stolen object isn't mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, in modern usage, if *you* have *it,* and *I* take *it,* then *I* am **robbing *you* of *it*** and **stealing *it* from *you***. Why? Because that's the way these verbs work.

It used to be the case that one could say that *I* was **robbing *it* from *you***, although this usage is apparently rare now.  Note the following [usage note](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rob) from Merrian-Webster:

> Sense *vt* 1c, in which the direct object is the thing stolen, is sometimes considered to be wrong, or perhaps archaic. The sense has been in use since the 13th century and is found in earlier literature . It is still in use though not as common as other senses .

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at both.

1. > I will rob you of it.

   *Of* is a preposition. *It* is a pronoun.
2. > I will rob it *off* you.

   Not "*of* you".

#1 is more metaphoric. "I will rob you of your honor." "I'll rob you of it."
#2 means "I will rob/steal it from you".

Both constructions are correct, though the usage is different.

Comment: *Rob it off you* also sounds more colloquial.